# extract just one element from list and write it into a csv as another name

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a list:

```
IDs = ["111111111111", "222222222222"]
```

and create a csv with this code:

```
for acc in IDs:
    with open("/tmp/test.csv", "a+") as f: 
            test = csv.writer(f)
            test.writerow([IDs])
```

result is:

```
{'111111111111', '222222222222'}
```

what i want to do is like:

```
if IDs == "111111111111":
    IDs = "AccountA"
elif IDs == "222222222222":
    IDs = "AccountB"
```

expected result in csv:

```
Account A
    some information about account a i put later on it
Account B
    some information about account a i put later on it
```

How can I achieve the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary. What you do is you create a dictonary with all data. At the left side you would have your input, and and the right side you have your data that your want to write. For this case, take a look at this dictionary:

```py
data = {
  '111111111111':'AccountA',
  '222222222222':'AccountB'
}
```

Than, create a loop around your list and create a new list, with the new ids, configured with your data.

```py
new_ids = []
for x in ids:
  new_ids.append(data[x])
```

Now, you can use the new_ids list to use in your write function.

Hope it helps.
Sincerly, Chris Fowl.

Comment: @Tomalak does almost the same, but he checks the corresponding value at writing time. My code is a little more simplistic (not using list comprehension), but is less Pythonic. You couls replace the creation of my list (new_ids) with his line that is in parentheses in the writelines function.

Comment: okay, in itself it works, but apparently I did not express myself correctly :D.. now I get as result ```['Account A, Account B] Information of Account A ['Account A, Account B] Information of Account B```, but I want  ```Account A, Information of Account A Account B Information of Account B``` you know what I mean?

Comment: You mean a dictionary with those, as ```{Account A:Information of Account A, Account B: Information of Account B}``` or with a list, like: ```[Account A, Information of Account A]``` & ```[Account B, Information of Account B]```. I would suggest you would use nested dictionaries like this: ```{'Account A':{'Password':'pass', 'Name':'uid'}, 'Account B':{'Password':'pass','Name':'uid'}```

Comment: I mean without {} or [].. You know how to realise that? Maybe you can edit your answere?

Comment: Not in Python directly, however you can write it to a file like that, if so, how'ld you want to format it?

Comment: Oh, and maybe you can edit your question to your actual needs.